# How can I include a hyperlink as a parameter in Express?

Tags: json, node.js, express, hyperlink

I'm trying to send a hyperlink (such as: "http://google.com") as a parameter to my Express server script. My current script looks like this:

```
var app = require("express")();

app.get("/new/:link(*)", function(req, res){
    var link = req.params.link;
    res.end(JSON.stringify({
        site: link
    }));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    console.log("Listening...");
});
```

This is just a test to see if I can get it working so I can build something bigger on top. The idea is that I can send a link and receive the link in JSON. However when I try to go to the site with the the link as parameter, my browser want to save a file called "google.com" and it doesn't receive any JSON from the server.

I know it's possible to do this without changing anything about my browser but I don't know how. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to redirect the browser to the url that's supplied in link, or do you want to proxy it?

Comment: I simply want to display it at this stage. The idea is to use it with mongodb later on. So right now, just display a JSON like: {site: "http://google.com"}

Comment: Your example works alright with me. What's the OS/browser?

Comment: Ubuntu and firefox. But the weird thing is that a website that does the exact same thing doesn't try to save anything using the same os and browser.

Comment: Btw if you send a link along, it has to contain the protocol as well

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have accidentally fixed my problem.

Apparently i had to write "res.send(...)" instead of "end". It now works perfectly although I don't really understand why.